# Reading RFID tags from multiple antennas through Motorola Reader FX7500 - Java

Tags: java, rfid, motorola, motorola-emdk, reader

I have Motorola FX 7500 and two antennas. I have placed the two antennas at the entrance gate so that the antennas face each other.
I am able to successfully read the TAG values from the individual antennas but what I want is a single value for both the antennas. ( I do understand that at times one antenna might catch a tag few micro seconds earlier than the other but there should be a way for synchronizing the results. Few questions on this:

1. Is there a way that the tag results from the two antennas be synchronized so that if one sends the other wont.
2. Is there a way that a tag reading code be saved in the reader rather than attaching a computer to it. I was working with the Speedway readers and the code stays within the reader without a need to attach the computer for the middleware code.

Kindly advise and help.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you use a single reader, right? In that case, the reader will 'multiplex' in time, so first read on antenna one, then on antenna two, then on again again, etc.

So, the timestamps of your read events will be not overlapping. You need to do a bit of software filtering on top of that to 'associate' the reads on one antenna to another.

I *think* that you can do the same think with Motorola readers, as with Impinj's - see here for more information: https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/XP-EN/Mobile+Networks+RFID+and+BarCode+Scanners/RFID+Products/FX7500%20RFID. "RFID SDK for FX7500 v1.2.2 - Embedded programming"